# Select All Records From One Table And Matching Record From Other Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I work for several hours just to get the result that I want on my SQL code but without luck. I'm trying to select all records from one table and matching records from other table.

Please see the live sample [here](http://rextester.com/edit/AFO66895).

```
url_id  short_url   campaign    Clicks
1       test1       campaign1   2
2       test2       campaign2   2
```

SQL code from above sample:

```
SELECT u.url_id, u.short_url, c.campaign, Count(*) AS Clicks
FROM (urls u LEFT JOIN log l ON l.url_id = u.url_id) LEFT JOIN campaign c ON u.campaign_id = c.campaign_id
WHERE (((DATE_FORMAT(l.date_time, '%Y-%m-%d')) Between '2017-03-14' And '2017-03-17'))
GROUP BY u.url_id, u.short_url, c.campaign;
```

What I want on the results is this. Include all records from urls table.

```
url_id  short_url   campaign    Clicks
1       test1       campaign1   2
2       test2       campaign2   2
3       test3       campaign1   0
4       test4                   0
```

I tried adding `l.url_id is null` in the WHERE clause but the clicks has a value of 1 instead of zero (0)

```
url_id  short_url   campaign    Clicks
1       test1       campaign1   2
2       test2       campaign2   2
3       test3       campaign1   1
4       test4                   1
```

SQL code from above sample:

```
SELECT u.url_id, u.short_url, c.campaign, Count(*) AS Clicks
FROM (urls u LEFT JOIN log l ON l.url_id = u.url_id) LEFT JOIN campaign c ON u.campaign_id = c.campaign_id
WHERE (((DATE_FORMAT(l.date_time, '%Y-%m-%d')) Between '2017-03-14' And '2017-03-17')) or l.url_id is null
GROUP BY u.url_id, u.short_url, c.campaign;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be conceptually easier to just aggregate over the `log` table, since this is what is generating the click counts, not the other tables.  Going along those lines we can try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.url_id,
       t1.short_url,
       COALESCE(t2.campaign, 'NA') AS campaign,
       COALESCE(t3.num_clicks, 0) AS Clicks
FROM urls t1
LEFT JOIN campaign t2
    ON t1.campaign_id = t2.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT url_id, COUNT(*) AS num_clicks
    FROM log
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2017-03-14' AND '2017-03-17'
    GROUP BY url_id
) t3
    ON t1.url_id = t3.url_id;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thank you very much. It works and it's also faster than using `is null`.

Comment: @jaypabs I'm actually surprised that it's faster than the other two answers, but from a code maintenance point of view, I think my query is much easier to read and maintain.  If you need to add a non aggregate column to the query, it would be simple, whereas in your original approach this might not be the case.

Comment: Yes. It's too way faster than the two answers, and I thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `COUNT(l.id)` in place of `COUNT(*)`.

Add `l.date_time IS NULL` in `WHERE` clause.

Check http://rextester.com/YOX73980

```
SELECT u.url_id, u.short_url, c.campaign, Count(l.id) AS Clicks
FROM urls u 
LEFT JOIN log l ON l.url_id = u.url_id 
LEFT JOIN campaign c ON u.campaign_id = c.campaign_id
WHERE l.date_time IS NULL OR (DATE_FORMAT(l.date_time, '%Y-%m-%d')) Between '2017-03-14' And '2017-03-17'
GROUP BY u.url_id, u.short_url, c.campaign;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.url_id, u.short_url, c.campaign, Count(c.campaign_id) AS Clicks
FROM urls u LEFT JOIN log l ON l.url_id = u.url_id 
LEFT JOIN campaign c ON u.campaign_id = c.campaign_id 
AND (((DATE_FORMAT(l.date_time, '%Y-%m-%d')) Between '2017-03-14' And '2017-03-17')) 
GROUP BY u.url_id, u.short_url, c.campaign;
```

Check [**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05e196/4)